# Filtering on recent files Microsoft Graph API not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to fetch recently accessed items for a user using [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). While fetching the items themselves works, I am unable to filter on lastModifiedDateTime, which is a property of the API response, as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships).

I am making a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2020-08-25T05:30:00Z
```

And I am getting a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException` with the following message:

```
'The expression "lastModifiedDateTime ge 2020-08-25T05:30:00Z" is not valid.'
```

Please help!

Comment: This error is mainly due to single quotes(') missing in between timestamp. And after putting that you get an "Invalid Filter Clause" error. It would be better to filter it on your end and use the data since most of the properties doesn't support filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Shiva-MSFTIdentity. I ended up doing what you suggested. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Utkarsh. Moving this to answer.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which is showing up says 'The expression "lastModifiedDateTime ge 2020-08-25T05:30:00Z" is not valid' which means the expression which you have given in the filter is not right. You need to correct it as shown below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2020-08-25T05:30:00Z'
```

But still this call doen't work because the filter is not supported on this property and you will end up 'Invalid filter clause'.

As a work around you can get the recent files and filter it on your end as most of the properties doesn't support filtering yet.